# How to Populate a Checkbox: C# vs T-SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, datatable

Sorry for the R101 question.

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a list of items (itemID, Title). I have another table with boxes (boxID, Title). I then have a lookup table that identifies which items go into which boxes.

What is the best way to list **all** the items with a checkbox checked to show which items are in a box depending on a selected boxID?

Probably a T-SQL statement would be better than a convoluted C# datatable. I've had a few attempts but just cant get the right result.

**EDIT**: Sorry I've not been very clear. I need to present a list of all items with a checkbox next to each item. I want checkbox.checked against any item where the boxID has an equivalent item ID next to it in the lookup table.

The result should have have ideally the itemID, itemName and a boolean column to show whether to check the checkbox or not.

The idea is that when the 'box' is being updated items can be amended etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want two things:

1) A list of all items

2) A list of all items in boxes

You can do this in a couple of ways (I'm guessing the structure of your tables here - I'm guessing ItemBox is the link table)

a) Select all of the items, then select a list of all of the items in boxes:

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
       I.Title,
       B.BoxId,
       B.Title

FROM   Item I
INNER JOIN ItemBox IB ON (I.ItemID = IB.ItemID)
INNER JOIN Box B ON (IB.BoxID = B.BoxID)

ORDER BY B.Title, I.Title
```

Should give you all of the items and their boxes.

You can then display a list of all items in a form, and a list of box ids (just simple selects from each table).

If you cache the results from the above query (in say a dictionary, BoxItem dictionary) then you can look up the item quite simply based on the selected Box.

b) you can run the query each time a box is selected:

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
       I.Title,
       B.BoxId,
       B.Title

FROM   Item I
INNER JOIN ItemBox IB ON (I.ItemID = IB.ItemID)
INNER JOIN Box B ON (IB.BoxID = B.BoxID)

WHERE B.Id = @selected_boxid

ORDER BY B.Title, I.Title
```

And update accordingly.

Do you need examples for running the query, binding to various controls etc?

Here's a version that should do what you want based on your comment:

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
      I.Title,
        CASE 
           WHEN IB.ItemID IS NULL THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END AS ItemIsInBox


FROM   Item I
LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemBox IB ON (I.ItemID = IB.ItemID);
```

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like one result that returns itemID, itemName and a bool column indicating which itemIDs are listed in the lookup table. The lookup table is populated with just itemIDs and boxIDs. the bool column is dependant on @boxID.

Comment: I've added added a bit more sql at the bottom of the example. If you are familiar with the OUTER JOIN operator then you'll know that this matches all rows in both tables, plus returns null for those rows that don't match. You can use this to see which are in the link table and which aren't

Comment: Thanks for that. I had kinda got that far minus the CASE WHEN. However, this just returns 1 for everything as there is at least one item in each box. But thanks to you I've amended it so: SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT I.itemID, I.Title, CASE WHEN IB.BoxID = @boxID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ItemIsInBox
FROM Item AS I LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemBox AS IB ON I.itemID = IB.itemID ORDER BY I.itemID. But it has an issue - see next comment

Comment: The problem is that items that are in a particular box are repeated with a row for both a 1 and a 0. All items that are not selected with @boxID are returned correctly. I have 288 items and if one selects box ID 397 say, which has 8 items in it, the result returns 296 results (8 with a 1 as expected in ItemsIsInBox but a further 8 with the same itemID but with a 0 for ItemsIsInBox. I don't understand how the duplication is occurring. BTW I've checked for duplicate entries in the Lookup table which would cause it.

Comment: Do you have 8 repeated ItemId's that aren't in the same box? When specifying the box name, I'd make the query an inner join, as you want to match things that are ONLY in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed the duplicate items:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT I.itemID, I.Title, CASE WHEN IB.BoxID = @boxID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ItemIsInBox 
FROM Item AS I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemBox AS IB ON I.itemID = IB.itemID AND **IB.BoxID = @boxID**
ORDER BY I.itemID
```

Thought it was worth sharing. Thanks for your help. You all helped to get me here.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have the 2nd table link box ID to item ID, or otherwise you'd have to make sure that in both tables Title is unique.

For your question, I'd venture:

```
SELECT ItemId, Title FROM Table1 WHERE Title IN (SELECT Title FROM Table2 WHERE BoxId = @boxId)
```

Comment: The item table consists of itemID, itemname. the lookup table just has itemID and boxID. So I want to list all items and just bool result (ultimately) against each cartID that appears in the lookup table based on @boxID. I swapped title with item ID but I only get a list of which items are in the lookup.